# Adding special characters to number input

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I'm trying to create a HTML duration(not time of day) input field, ie HH:MM, and I would like it to trigger the numeric keyboard on mobile devices.

`<input type="number" />` appears to be the only reliable way to make this happen. But I require it to accept colons `:`.

Is there a way to force the number input field accept additional special characters?

Comment: Why not use a TimePicker which was built for exactly this kind of input?

Comment: Time pickers are for time of day, eg 12:45pm - I just want specifically hours and minutes as a duration, eg. This task to 5 hours 30 minutes to complete. It doesn't make much sense for am/pm to be there.

Comment: You can put the picker into 24 hour mode which removes the AM/PM indicator.  Could be fine if you don't need hours > 23.

Comment: Is there a reliable way to force 24hours? I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: There's an API method on TimePicker to set that mode.  I can't speak to its reliability, but I can find nothing to suggest it's flaky.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible. As you need the numeric keyboard on mobile device along with `:` is not native at all. There is just no `:` key in the keyboard, nothing you can do about it.

Just use `<input type=time>`
 and you can make magic happen nicely on mobile device. If you need the user to type in, use `number` or `text`, and add additional `pattern` property to perform the validation. Or use something like [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org)
 to perform just in time validation.

Comment: Time pickers are for time of day, eg 12:45pm - I just want specifically hours and minutes as a duration, eg. This task to 5 hours 30 minutes to complete. It doesn't make much sense for am/pm to be there.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_input_time_create nope, try it on mobile device (in my case ios8.4) it only let you select hour and minute.

Answer (score 0):

Try for HH:MM entry and H:MM entry

```
<EditText>
     android:digits="1234567890:"
     android:inputType="textNosuggestions" 
     android:minLength="4"
     android:maxLength="5"/>
```

If you want to prevent users from entering time like "91:87", or ":36" or ":3:4" and all such variations then you would have to use a TextWatcher like this `edistext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(this));`

Comment: Is this for an android app? I'm trying to make an input for a web app.

Comment: why have you tagged android then?? wasted my time

Comment: but you don't require a solution in android.